# Existence of bounded solution for a set of first order linear differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Prove that the following combined linear differential equations of real-valued unknown (continuous) functions u(x),v(x)
$$\left\{
  \begin{array}{@{}ll@{}}
    (\frac{d}{dx}-k)v(x)=\mu(x)u(x) &  \\
    (\frac{d}{dx}+k)u(x)=\mu(x)v(x), & 
  \end{array}\right.$$
where $\mu(x)$ is a monotonously increasing real-valued (not necessarily continuous) function of $x$ with $\mu(+\infty)=1$ and $\mu(-\infty)=-1$ (in the limit sense), have no solutions satisfying $u(+\infty)=v(+\infty)=u(-\infty)=v(-\infty)=0$ unless the real parameter $k=0$.

For example, if $\mu(x)=\mathrm{sgn}(x)$, then when x>0 we have 
$$\left\{
  \begin{array}{@{}ll@{}}
    u(x)=u_0 \exp(-\sqrt{k^2+1}x) &  \\
    v(x)=v_0 \exp(-\sqrt{k^2+1}x), & 
  \end{array}\right.$$
where $u_0/v_0=-(k+\sqrt{k^2+1})$, and for $x<0$ we have
$$\left\{
  \begin{array}{@{}ll@{}}
    u(x)=u'_0 \exp(\sqrt{k^2+1}x) &  \\
    v(x)=v'_0 \exp(\sqrt{k^2+1}x), & 
  \end{array}\right.$$
where $u'_0/v'_0=k-\sqrt{k^2+1}$. But continuity requires $u_0/v_0=u'_0/v'_0$
which is impossible unless $k=0$.

I'm wondering how to prove the statement for a general $\mu(x)$. Could anybody give me any ideas? Thanks!:)